# C++ calling Python how to deal with SystemExit exception

Tags: python, c++, exception, interface, python-embedding

I have a C++ code which executes Python script using the `PyRun_SimpleFileEx` C API.

The py file looks like this

```
import time

time.sleep(2)
raise SystemExit("Sorry, it is time to exit.")
```

SystemExit is what is also raised by calling python stuff like either `quit()` or `abort()`

Since SystemExit inherits from BaseException instead of Exception it is not catched and shuts-off the Python environment as well as the C++ application.

Is there any way to catch the exception above from C++?

Thanks in advance
All the best
MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `wrapper.py` and run the code from it.

```py
class ExceptionWrapper(Exception):
    def __init__(self, exc):
        self.exc = exc

def run_code(filename):
    try:
        exec(open(filename).read(), globals=globals(), locals=locals())
    except BaseException as ex:
        raise ExceptionWrapper(ex)
```

Using this wrapper from C++:

```cpp
#include <Python.h>

int main() {
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject * wrapper = PyImport_ImportModule("wrapper");
    if (!wrapper) {
        PyErr_Print();
        exit(1);
    }
    PyObject * res = PyObject_CallMethod(wrapper, "run_code", "s", "simple.py");
    if (!res) {
        PyErr_Print();
        // PyObject *type, *value, *traceback;
        // PyErr_Fetch(&type, &value, &traceback);
        // PyErr_NormalizeException(&type, &value, &traceback);
        // or handle exception manually here
        // PyErr_Restore(type, value, traceback);
    }
    Py_XDECREF(res);
    printf("exit from C\n");
}
```

Please note that this is just a POC and it is not safe to run arbitrary code.

You can modify the wrapper to accept a file descriptor as argument.

Comment: Hello, this sounds reasonable and I'll explore further the solution. I'm wondering if it is possible to define a module directly in memory instead to load it from file. That'd be better in my case. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: yes compile it to a pyc and define it as a frozen module. take a look at cpython on github. [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Tools/freeze/freeze.py), [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Makefile.pre.in#L720-L744), [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/importlib_external.h) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html#c._inittab)

Comment: you can replace the `PyImport_FrozenModules` before initialize do not forget to copy its content to the new list otherwise the interpreter will be broken.

Comment: I did it differently and I have got an accettable result. Basically I put the wrapper in a module built directly with 'PyModule_New' and called the function as you told in the C++ code. Thanks a lot for your help. Yout answer deserves to be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will turn useful to someone else:

using the `PyRun_File*` C API family makes the outer C++ application to stay in place (no shut-off).

The script will fail and the PyObject pointer returned by the function will be invalid to indicate that